# Clustered monotonically increased index insert performance

Tags: sql-server-2008, performance, execution-plan, clustered-index, clustered-primary-key

I have a table with field `Id` (`bigint`, `IDENTITY`) as *primary key* and *clustered* index on it.
I inserted 400 rows and saw execution plan. I got: the relative query cost for this insertion 36% and for this query "Clustered Index Insert"'s cost 97%. What's going on? Why does it work so slow?

**ADDED:**

[image]

continue
[image]

See also [SQL Server insert performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457837/sql-server-insert-performance)

Comment: Is it actually slow? What are the timings? What else does the batch do such that the cluster insert is 97%? I.e. what consumes the other 3%?

Comment: @Mark Inserted scan or Deleted scan 3% -> Top 0% -> Compute Scalar 0% -> Compute Scalar 0% -> Clustered Index Insert 97%

Comment: @Mark Total batch execution time 34 seconds, relative problem query cost 36% (I have the second one  with the almost same cost 37%). So 73% of 34 seconds is too much, what do you think? Oh, these inserts are performed in trigger. :)

Comment: Suggest you post the execution plan and scripts for the insert and triggers, it's blind guesswork otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relative cost of the components of an execution plan is not always reliable.

The INSERTED scan or deleted scan shouts TRIGGER to me. This is your problem most likely.

Are you looping over 400 rows and sending an email in an extreme example?

Comment: no, I am doing some calculations, getting 400 records and insert them in transaction. strange. Also I am doing some checks in trigger (checking update mask with stored one in table). maybe it is better to stop doing this and compare mask with predefined one.

Comment: It seams execution plan cheats :). Result does not depends on how many records code inserts (or too indirectly depends), it estimates ONLY. Thank you.